# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ at $(1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to show that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable at $(1,1)$ by doing the following but I got stuck:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\longrightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(1+h,1+k)-f(1,1)-f_x(1,1)h-f_y(1,1)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{(h,k)\longrightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\frac{(1+h)(1+k)}{(1+h)^2+(1+k)^2}-\frac{1}{2}-0-0}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{(h,k)\longrightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\frac{2(1+h)(1+k)-(1+h)^2-(1+k)^2}{2[(1+h)^2+(1+k)^2]}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{(h,k)\longrightarrow(0,0)}\frac{-(h-k)^2}{2[(1+h)^2+(1+k)^2]\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

Would appreciate any help from hence forth. Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Perhaps you have to check differentiability at $(0,0)$?

Comment: $f$ has continuous partial derivatives in a neighborhood of $(1,1)$.

Comment: I checked that it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Is that related to differentiability at $(1,1)$?

Comment: @geetha290krm That is helpful! Should I abandon my approach using definition of differentiability?

Comment: Using your method, it ultimately suffices to show $|h-k|/\sqrt{h^2+k^2} \leq 2$

Comment: Quick tip: You might want to use the fact that if $f(t), g(t)$ are both differentiable at some $t=a$, then for $h(t)=\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ we have $h'(a)=\frac{f'(a)g(a)-f(a)g'(a)}{g(a)^2}$. This way you only have to compute partial derivatives of polynomials first.

Comment: @KHOOS I don't know what you already learned about differentiability. Here, $f$ is the ratio of two polynomials that are differentiable, with the denominator not vanishing around $(1,1)$. Hence the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y)$ is $C^1$ in a neigbourhood of $(1,1)$ and hence it is differentiable. However, if you want to prove it by the definition, note that as $(x,y)\to (1,1)$, the quantity $(1+h)^2+(1+k)^2$ is bigger than $1$. Now use polar coordinates:

$$0\le\left|\frac{(h-k)^2}{[(1+h)^2+(1+k)^2]\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\right|\le \frac{(h-k)^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\frac{\rho^2(1-\sin 2\vartheta)}{\rho}\le 2\rho \to 0 $$

Comment: This is so elegant. Thanks!

Comment: @KHOOS you're welcome my friend

Comment: It should be noted that pointwise convergence as $\rho \to 0$ isn't sufficient, but in this case, the convergence at the end is uniform with respect to $\theta$, which _is_ sufficient.  I personally would insert $$\frac{\rho^2(1-\sin 2\vartheta)}{\rho} \leq 2\rho \to 0$$ to avoid the confusion with the common error.

Comment: @BrianMoehring right, I'll edit it